# Output a duration with clock() but output is multiplied

Tags: c++, clock

So, I want to display duration the program has been opened in secs,
but it displayed multiply secs instead of one character. Ex. 1 to 11111
Here's the code:

```
int main() {
   clock_t start;
   double duration;
   int seconds;

   start = clock();
   while (true) {
      if ((clock() - start) % CLOCKS_PER_SEC == 0) {
        cout << (clock() - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
      }
   }
}
```

Output :

```
01111111111111111111111222222222233333333333334444444445555555556666666666666667777777777777
```

Help me solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` check is completely wrong. Imagine if your `while` loop runs twice and there's no change in `clock()` because it loops very fast. It will either output both times or output neither time. That can't possibly be right.

The correct check is to see if at least one second has passed since the last time you produced output.

```
 clock_t last_output;
 start = last_output = clock();
 while (true) {
      if (clock() > (last_output + CLOCKS_PER_SEC)){
          last_output += CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
          cout << (clock() - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    }
 }
```

Here's the full code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    clock_t start, last_output;

    start = last_output = clock();
    while (true)
    {
        if (clock() > (last_output + CLOCKS_PER_SEC))
        {
            last_output += CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            std::cout << (clock() - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;
        }
     }
}
```